# Reducing the space between radio label lines

Tags: html, css, vue.js, radio-button

I have a radiobutton that has two lines as a label. The whitespace between the lines are two much and I want to decrease them.

This is my code:

```
          <label for="reg-promo">
            <input type="radio" name="promotion" id="registerPromo" v-validate="'required'" checked="checked"
              v-model="registerPromo" value="reg-promo" />
            <span>
              <b>Welcome Offer</b>
              <p id="welcomeOfferSubtext">$35 in credits available</p>
            </span>
          </label>
```

`welcomeOfferSubtext` just simply adds `28px` padding to the left of the paragraph:

```
#welcomeOfferSubtext {
    padding-left: 28px;
  }
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

What's the best way to fix it?

P.S

Please ignore the sentence differences. The focus is on spacing
I don't want to use `line-height` from CSS

Comment: Use `display: flex` on main <label>... then apply the `margin-right` in the radio input or `margin-left` in the span that content the <b> and <p> https://jsfiddle.net/om9kudLs/7/

Comment: Please note I'm talking about the vertical space not the horizontal space.

Answer (score 0):

The extra vertical space is probably coming from some other (or browser default) `<p>` CSS.

Either change the `<p id="welcomeOfferSubtext">` to `<div id="welcomeOfferSubtext">`

Or add to your css:

```
#welcomeOfferSubtext {
    padding-left: 28px;
    margin: 0; // add this line
  }
```

Comment: In that case, try Google Chrome dev tools, right click on the `$35 in bonus credits...` text and click on `Inspect` in the menu.  Then using the dev tools try to see where the extra vertical space is coming from, then try to override that.  As a last resort you could always use something like `#welcomeOfferSubtext { margin-top: -20px}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly make span as inline-block, so that all elements within span will be aligned to span. Now you can do your css accordingly. <p> tag has some default margin, you can then modify it accordingly.

<style>
span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#welcomeOfferSubtext{
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
```